# How can I encrypt/decrypt a text field on the fly with django

Tags: django, django-models, encryption

To simplify, I have a model called Entry with the following fields

- entry_date
- description

I have a form created with both the fields mapped to it. I want to encrypt the description field while storing in a sqlite database, and decrypt it when retrieving it and displaying for the user interface.

I read that I need to create a custom class and implement the encryption and decryption methods in that class. I created a custom class called EncryptedDescription, and added the get_prep_value and from_db_value that saves/retrieves the new field from the database.

But should this new custom class (e.g. encrypted_description) be an additional field in my Entry model? Or should I replace the description field with the encrypted_description field?

Additionally, how do I map this custom class to a django model form? When I try to add the encrypted_description it gives me an error "encrypted_description cannot be specified for  model form as it is a non-editable field"

I've browsed through so many examples but I'm still confused about the above two questions. Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 3):

To encrypt and decrypt a specific column in Django, you can use the `django-cryptography` package. I used this package to achieve encryption in my project. All you need to do is wrap the field in your model with the `encrypt` function, and it will take care of the rest. You can also use a custom signature and customize the type of encryption. For more information on how to do this, refer to the documentation.

https://django-cryptography.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Create feild as @property and overwiter it setter and getter.

1. Replace the model fieldName with other name(_fieldName)
2. Create fieldName property as a getter.
3. Create a property setter

For example

```py
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry_date = models.DateField()
        self._description = models.TextField(db_column='description')

    @property
    def description(self):
        # Decrypt the value of self._description and return
        val = decrypt(self._description)
        return val

    @description.setter
    def description(self, val):
        # Encrypt val and update self._description value
        enc_val = encrypt(val)
        self._description = enc_val
```

Comment: where this decrypt function came? Can you print the full source code? Currently i am having issues when i want to decrypt my fields.